# Suppress HTML name of a character (like quotes or &) in ColdFusion form

Tags: regex, forms, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion form that I need to scrub some offending code from and still keep some basic punctuation.

In my development I've set up a function with `ReReplaceNoCase()` and a pile of RegEx to clean just about everything and leave me with 3 different variables. one is used to rename a photo, the other ecomes the alt ad title and the third becomes the headline for the product in an `<h1>` tag

But I've encountered a strange problem. In my input I get the HTML name for some things like `&quot;` for double quotes but not for single quotes.

For example, when I have a string like `""Great" leather harnesses & More!"` I get back 3 strings useable for my project:

`_Great_leather_harnesses_and_more_` - which concats with `.jpg` to become the file name

`Great leather harnesses and more` - which become alt and title attributes

and `Great leather harnesses and more!` - becomes my `<h1>`

The trouble is my form submits `&quot;` for the double quotes and `&amp;` for the & but `!` for the exclamation point.

What can I do to force my form to post ONLY the character to my function so I don't have to go through every character with an HTML name and zap it? By the way, I'm getting the same results with either `<input type="text"...` and `<textarea>`.

Here's my scrubing bubles of RegEx:

```
<cfset string = #form.product_name#>
    <cfset replaceQuotes = ReReplaceNoCase(string, "(&quo;)", "", "all")>
    <cfset replaceAnd = ReReplaceNoCase(replaceQuotes, "(&amp;)|(&)|(amp;)", " and ", "all")>
    <cfset replacePercent = ReReplaceNoCase(replaceAnd, "\%", " Percent ", "all")>
    <cfset scrubName = ReReplaceNoCase(replacePercent, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "_", "all")>
    <cfset cleanFileName = ReReplaceNoCase(scrubName, "[_]{2,}", "_", "all")>
    <cfset cleanAlt = ReReplaceNoCase(scrubName, "[_]", " ", "all")>
    <cfset headlinetoClean = ReReplaceNoCase(replacePercent, "[^a-zA-Z0-9.,!'\-\+]", " ", "all")>
    <cfset cleanHeadline = ReReplaceNoCase(headlinetoClean, "[\s]{2,}", " ", "all")>
```

If it matters I'm declaring `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the head of the page...

Edit - Added form and validation code -

And my form:

```
<cfform name="newProduct" id="newProduct" >
<label for="product_name">Product Name: </label><cfinput name="product_name" id="product_name" style="width:300px;"/>
<cfinput name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Create Page" />
</cfform>
```

Some validation - I suspect this may be the issue? :

```
<cfif not len(trim(form.product_name))>
    <cfset arrayAppend( errors, "You forgot to name the product")>
<cfelse>
    <cfset form.product_name = htmlEditFormat(trim(form.product_name))>
</cfif>
```

I'm pretty fresh at this RegEx so I'm sure there's a smarter way to go about this. But, this mechanism does seem to work, mostly.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, can you provide example input and desired output that you're having problems with?

Comment: It is very generally a bad idea to rely on the client not giving you bad or unwanted input. Your task is to accept *any input whatsoever* and clean it until it meets your requirements. Anything else is asking for trouble. Literally.

Comment: @Tomalak - Well, that's my point behind all this. I'm trying to accept everything and scrub accordingly. But I can't figure out when my form is going to submit an actual character or some sporadic HTML name.

Comment: @Ofeargall: Well, it looks like you are in need of an actual HTML parser, then. It will fix your input HTML, parse any character entities into characters and allow structured access to the contents. There is none built-in for ColdFusion, but there are a couple of parsers for Java that you could download and use.

Comment: @Ofeargall, that your form is submitting HTML entities (e.g. `&quot`) seems unusual. Can you post your form code so others can reproduce?

Comment: @orangepips I think I may have spotted the trouble. Maybe you can confirm. I've edited my post to include a piece of the code that performs the form validation. In it I'm using htmlEditFormat(). I suspect that may be the culprit?

Comment: @Ofeargall: your suspicion is correct, `HTMLEditFormat()` is the problem - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7847.html - it escapes `<>&"`.

Comment: @orangepips, if you'll put that into an answer I'll give it a check-mark. I feel ridiculous for not seeing that sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, HTMLEditFormat() is the problem - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7847.html - it escapes `<>&"`.